# Pandas to parquet NOT into file-system but get content of resulting file in variable

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

There are several ways how a conversion from pandas to parquet is possible. e.g. pyarrow.Table.from_pandas or dataframe.to_parquet . What they have in common is that they get as a parameter a filePath where the df.parquet should be stored.

I need to get the content of the written parquet file into a variable and have not seen this, yet. Mainly I want the same behavior as pandas.to_csv which returns the result as a string if no path is provided.

Of course I could just write the file and read it with standard file reading operations from python into a string. As I'm writing a ton of data, this would produce a lot of load on the file system ... .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either use io.BytesIO for this or alternatively Apache Arrow also provides its native implementation BufferOutputStream. The benefit of this is that this writes to the stream without the overhead of going through Python. Thus less copies are made and the GIL is released.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

df = some pandas.DataFrame
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
buf = pa.BufferOutputStream()
pq.write_table(table, buf)
# buf now contains the Parquet file in memory.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just to clarify, after the execution of 'pq.write_table(table, buf)', buf contains the content of the parquet file. If I would do f = open("demofile.txt", "w")
f.write(buf) then demofile would be equivalent to demofile_2 with df.to_parquet(fname="demofile_2.txt") ?
I know, this might sound strange to you but the background is that I want to provide another piece of code with the content and that piece of code is going to write it to "some" file system exactly as i hand it over.

Comment: Yes, that should be equal