# How to write pyarrow parquet data to s3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, pyarrow

I have created a dataframe and converted that df to a parquet file using pyarrow (also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54669196/pandas-to-parquet-not-into-file-system-but-get-content-of-resulting-file-in-vari)) :

```
def convert_df_to_parquet(self,df):
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
    buf = pa.BufferOutputStream()
    pq.write_table(table, buf)
    return buf
```

Now i want to save upload that to s3 bucket and tried different input parameters for `upload_file()`everything i tried did not work:

```
s3_client.upload_file(parquet_file, bucket_name, destination_key)#1st
s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=destination_key, Body=parquet_file)#2nd
s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=destination_key, Body=parquet_file.getvalue())#3rd
s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=destination_key, Body=parquet_file.read1())#4th
```

Errors:

```
 s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=destination_key, Body=parquet_file.read1())
  File "pyarrow/io.pxi", line 376, in pyarrow.lib.NativeFile.read1
  File "pyarrow/io.pxi", line 310, in pyarrow.lib.NativeFile.read
  File "pyarrow/io.pxi", line 320, in pyarrow.lib.NativeFile.read
  File "pyarrow/io.pxi", line 155, in pyarrow.lib.NativeFile.get_input_stream
  File "pyarrow/io.pxi", line 170, in pyarrow.lib.NativeFile._assert_readable
OSError: only valid on readonly files
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I can't seem to find a way to append pyarrow.lib.Table to a folder in s3

Answer (score 6):

Why not do it directly (Pandas -> S3) and speed it up?

```
import awswrangler as wr

wr.pandas.to_parquet(
    dataframe=df,
    path="s3://...",
    dataset=True,
    mode="overwrite",        # Could be append, overwrite or overwrite_partitions
    database="my_database",  # Optional, only with you want it available on Athena/Glue Catalog
    table="my_table",
    partition_cols=["PARTITION_COL_NAME"])
```

[Reference](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler)

Comment: Quick note: AWS has made breaking changes to the param names since this was posted. Here's the updated version:

def write_dataframe_to_parquet_in_s3(data, s3_path, database, table, **kwargs):

    wr.s3.to_parquet(
        df=data,
        path=s3_path,
        dataset=True,
        mode="overwrite",
        database=database,
        table=table,
        compression="snappy",
        max_rows_by_file=kwargs.get("max_rows_by_file", None),
        partition_cols=kwargs.get("partition_cols_list", None)
    )

Comment: I know the OP converted from pandas to pyarrow table then to s3, but I still think this is a valid question on how to upload a pyarrow table.

Answer (score 6):

One of the more annoying things about pandas is that if your token expires during a script then `pd.write_parquet("s3://...")` will `raise PermissionError` even if you're using `boto3.Session()`.  To get around this I wrote my own `pd.to_parquet()`:

```
def to_parquet(df, s3_path):
    """ Assumes path starts with s3:// """
    parts = s3_path[5:].split("/")
    bucket, key = (parts[0], "/".join(parts[1:]))

    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
    writer = pa.BufferOutputStream()
    pq.write_table(table, writer)
    body = bytes(writer.getvalue())

    session = boto3.Session(<private variables>)
    s3 = session.client("s3")
    s3.put_object(Body=body, Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

From [doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file)

Your should do similar to this,

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/'+parquet_file, bucket_name, parquet_file)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how you would write a pyarrow table to an s3 bucket.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

d = {'Column1': [1,2,3,4,5],
     'Column2': [6,7,8,9,0]}

table = pa.Table.from_pydict(d)

pq.write_to_dataset(table, root_path='s3://bucket-name/key-for-folder')
```